# Getting error while trying to migrate to Angular 9 : Error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol

Tags: angular, typescript, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I am trying to convert an Angular 8 app to Angular 9. While running migration command I see that i get:

```
Undecorated classes with DI migration.
      As of Angular 9, it is no longer supported to use Angular DI on a class that does not have an Angular decorator.
      Read more about this here: https://v9.angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes
    
        This migration uses the Angular compiler internally and therefore projects that no longer build successfully after the update cannot run the migration. Please ensure there are no AOT compilation errors and rerun the migration. The following project failed: libs/core/tsconfig.lib.json
    
        Error: ~/core-routing.module.ts:138:1: Error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol 'CoreRoutingModule':
         ~/core/src/lib/core-routing.module.ts:25:23: Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Lambda not supported.
          {"__symbolic":"error","message":"Lambda not supported","line":24,"character":22}
    
        Could not migrate all undecorated classes that use dependency
        injection. Some project targets could not be analyzed due to
        TypeScript program failures.
    
        Migration can be rerun with: "ng update @angular/core --migrate-only migration-v9-undecorated-classes-with-di"
    
      Migration completed.
```

`Nx workspace : 8.12.0`

`Angular : 8`

Answer (score 0):

strictMetadataEmit is a flag for libraries, So shouldn't have any lazy loaded modules at all. It's not meant to be used for applications.

```
"strictMetadataEmit": false,
```